# How do I refactor these conditionals in my ruby class?

Tags: ruby, refactoring

Here is my method. It checks if the file is usable. How do I dry this out?

```
@@filepath = nil

def self.file_usable?
  return false unless @@filepath
  return false unless File.exists?(@@filepath)
  return false unless File.readable?(@@filepath)
  return false unless File.writable?(@@filepath)
  return true
end
```

Should I be using some kind of loop?

Comment: What's wrong with what you have? That's an eminently readable presentation of the logic and very easy to grok at a glance.

Comment: @mu: do you really prefer this imperative return chain instead of a simple expression `a && b && c && d`?. Sorry, but I don't get it...

Comment: @tokland: I do, it is much easier to scan than a single line. You can achieve the same readability with a single expression with the suitable application of line breaks but Ruby makes you use backslashes or put the logical operators at the end of the line where they are somewhat obscured.

Comment: guys, I think what I have originally pasted is readable enough but I am a ruby newbie trying to learn what ruby can really do in a DRY way. So @tokland's snippet really teaches me a lot about the language

Comment: DRY doesn't apply here because you weren't repeating anything.

Comment: repeating the variable being acted upon doesn't count?

Comment: 4x "return false unless..." -- seems like it could benefit from DRYing :-)

Comment: If a file does not exist, `File.writable` will return false.

Comment: "DRY" != "short", "short" != "concise", "concise" != "readable", "concise" != "faster", etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't do it this way, but since you asked "to just refactor all these methods action on the same variable"...

```
def self.file_usable?
  @@filepath && [:exists?, :readable?, :writable?].all? { |m| File.send(m, @@filepath) }
end
```

This may be useful if you programatically need to decide which methods must be checked. If that's an isolated function, I'd write:

```
def self.file_usable?
  f = @@filepath
  f && File.exists?(f) && File.readable?(f) && File.writable?(f)
end
```

Comment: wow! I gotta see if that works. That looks like what I am looking for

Comment: You could actually take out the first @@filepath && by doing: [:exists?, :readable?, :writable?].all? { |m| File.send(m, @@filepath.to_s) } since nil.to_s is an empty string. But yes I agree, don't do it that way.

Answer (score 4):

```
def self.file_usable?
  @@filepath and File.exists?(@@filepath) and File.readable?(@@filepath) and File.writable?(@@filepath)
end
```

Comment: that's interesting but I notice all these methods are acting on the same variable. Isn't there a way to just refactor that out?

Comment: why the too specific `!@@filepath.nil?` if the OP is ok with `@@filepath` (detecting false/nil)?

Comment: @megas: note that your previous choice had a point in the sense that it returned always a boolean (the expected response being a `xyz?` method). A strict code would be `!!@@filepath`, though I wouldn't really bother (and this double !!@@ look funny :-))

Comment: you're right again, it could return nil. In Ruby only two values can be negative - nil and false, so it should not cause the trouble, am I right?

Comment: You can remove the File.exists?(@@filepath) part.

Comment: @megas: yes, you'd have problems only if you wrote `if method? == false` which of course nobody does.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [File#stat](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/File.html#method-c-stat) and check `mode` value.

```
s = File.stat("testfile")
other_can_rwx = s.mode && 0007
```

Answer (score 1):

I often use this technique when readability is my main concern:

```
def self.file_usable?
  [@@filepath,
   File.exists?(@@filepath),
   File.readable?(@@filepath),
   File.writable?(@@filepath)].all?
end
```

Do note however that there is a big difference in this approach, in that all expressions are evaluated.

The following works because `nil.some_method` is never called:

```
nil and nil.some_method
```

This however will throw an exception, because everything is always evaluated:

```
[nil, nil.some_method].all?
```

Answer (score 0):

It's probably not a good idea but you could theoretically do something like:

```
def self.file_usable?
  File.writable? @@filepath rescue nil
end
```

Comment: Downvoting like this is a great way of deterring people from offering answers to your questions in future. Fwiw Rescues like this are certainly smelly, but can get you over a hump.

Comment: I can see downvoting this answer in general but I *did* say it was a bad idea and it seemed like he wanted the shortest solution.

Comment: just to be clear: I did not downvote it. Appreciate your contribution pguardiario

Answer (score 0):

Another variation:

```
CHECK_METHODS = [:exists?, :readable?, :writable?] \
                  .map{ |m| File.method(m) } \
                  .unshift(lambda{ |x| x })


def self.file_usable?
  CHECK_METHODS.all? { |m| m[@@filepath] }
end
```